# Generating "weighted convex hull"

Tags: qgis, interpolation

sadly I don't have any keyword that reflects what I'm looking for:

I have a vector layer consisting of points, which have an integer attribute ("signal quality" here), that I want to plot as a convex hull. While the resulting shape is what I expected, I want to have some **colouring on the shape** that represents the quality level, too. IMHO a heatmap would only add simple spots, but is there a way to generate something that looks like a **weathermap** like multicolored shapes? I tried buffers but didn't managed it to bring everything playing together :/